# Call method named by user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to include a function in my terminal program (in python) that does the following:

Takes a command -
checks if it actually is a command -
if it is, run it -
if it's not, treat it as function.

Like so;

```
else:
    try:
        print("Navigating...")
        (input)()
```

as in, it would then try to go to def (input):

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `input()` is a built-in function that you should not override

Comment: Maybe you can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?